# Modifying url with .htaccess and symfony

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony-1.4

I'm working with symtfony 1.4 and I have a module named backend and its index file is

> wwww.domain.com/backend.php

But I want that when I write on the browser www.domain.com/back redirects me to

> www.domain.com/backend.php

I try with this rule

```
RewriteRule ^/back$ www.domain.com/backend.php
```

But it doesn't work.

This is my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
  # getting no_script_name to work
  #RewriteBase /

  # we skip all files with .something
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  #RewriteRule .* - [L]

  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  RewriteRule ^/back$ www.domain.com/backend.php 

  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
  RewriteRule ^/back$ www.domain.com/backend.php
```

to

```
  RewriteRule ^back$ http://www.domain.com/backend.php [L]
```

Comment: no, it returns "page not found". Is the position in the file important?

Comment: @jhrs21 yes, it needs to go above your other rules